What is this usage of “すごい的” and “言えよ”
The context is that a character is being hit on on the street and person doing so says:

大人の色気？ 脱いだらすごい的な。


お前エロいなー！ オクユカシイって言えよ。

The “的” following the plain form of an adjective I've never seen before. The “言えよ” I'd normally simply interpret as the command form followed by “〜よ” except it doesn't really make sense to tell anyone to say anything in this context.
Here's the original image:


It's not clear who's saying what. Can you paste the original scene as an image?

@naruto I've edited it with the original image.

@naruto, oh I actually understand it now that you point out it's not clear who's saying what. It's the other character that is telling the other pickup artist. I thought the use of “お前” stood out already. I thought the perso from the first line said the other one too. THe use of “的” I still don't understand though.

的 is basically a suffix meaning "-ish" or "-like", but in super-informal or frivolous speech, it can follow an entire clause (ending with the dictionary form) to add the same nuance. It's like "something like ～" or "kinda ～". This shouldn't be used in serious speech.

Understanding だった的なアレ
Why is しない used for a past event? (see ちょっとからかってた的なこと)

This 脱いだらすごい ("amazing when undressed", "hiding a lot under the clothes") is a cliché in Japanese, presumably from this ad in 1995. Here, this entire phrase has been suffixed with 的.
As for 言えよ, it's the other guy who said it. He pointed out that 脱いだらすごい was too direct, and they should have said 奥ゆかしい instead.

大人の色気？ 脱いだらすごい的な。
An adult charm, huh? That "amazing when undressed" kind (of charm)?
お前エロいなー！ オクユカシイって言えよ。
You're so lewd! Say "self-effacing" (instead)!

